# How to ANDed bitwise in assembler?

Tags: microcontroller, programming, microprocessor

Say I have a variable set to 30. In binary, 30 = 11110. I'd like to test some bits and then perform an action. For example, if bit 4 is set AND bit 3 is set AND bit 2 is set AND bit 1 is set THEN *perform action*. How can I do this in assembler?

Comment: This question needs more information for people to be able to help you.

Comment: What assembly language are you using? (i.e. is this for a PIC, 8051, Picoblaze, or?)

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to know if a certain set of bits in a word are 1 with the remaining bits irrelevant.  Let's call the word with the set of bits you want to test for the "mask".  In your case you want to test for bits 4, 3, 2, and 1 set and the rest irrelevant.  The mask would therefore be 11110.

The procedure is to AND the word to test with the mask, then check the result for being equal to the mask.  If it is, the bits in the mask are set.  For example:

```
word to test   10011110
mask           00011110
AND            00011110
```

Is the AND result equal to the mask?  In this case yes, so all the bits listed in the mask are set in the original word.  Here is a negative example:

```
word to test   10011010
mask           00011110
AND            00011010
```

As you can see, the AND result is not equal to the mask, so the answer is no.  In this case, the original word had bit 2 cleared, which is the reason the test failed.